# Actualizar un objeto de un array mongoose

Tags: javascript, array, json, mongodb, mongoose

quiero actualizar un objeto de mi array de objetos en mongoose pero no lo consigo, esta es mi objeto en la bd:

```
{
        "_id": "617c22d52fea166b39a57a8f",
        "nombre_comun": "Nombre comun",
        "nombre_cientifico": "NOmbre ciencia",
        "origen_distribucion": [],
        "descripcion": "Hola ",
        "comentarios": [
            {
                "fecha": {
                    "dia": "1970-01-01T00:00:00.005Z",
                    "mes": "1970-01-01T00:00:00.010Z",
                    "year": "1970-01-01T00:00:02.021Z"
                },
                "id_usuario": "617b5d0ac69b3345134d3f4a",
                "comentario": "Este es un comentario",
                "numero_reportes": 0,
                "estado_comentario": true,
                "_id": "618f398d3a9aa31e48a71d24"
            }
        ]
    }
```

**El arreglo que me interesa actualizar el el de comentarios**, en este objeto solo hay un comentario, y quiero actualizar su contenido como el numero de reportes, el estado de comentario y el cuerpo del comentario.

**No se como hacerlo.**

Comment: La solucion era sencilla:
`await Ficha.updateOne({ comentarios: { id_comentario }}, comentario);`
Lo busco a partir del arreglo de comentarios, por su id, y le paso que quiero actualizar de dicho objeto como segundo parametro.

Comment: Hola, podrías añadir como harías la consulta? filtras por el id del comentario?